# How to center javafx scene graph "camera"

Tags: java, javafx

I have a group with two circles on it, when I move one of them with a translate transition I should see the stationary one remain at the center(which is in the middle of the scene graph) and the other one move. Instead what happens is the "camera" follows the moving circle making it seem like they are both moving apart.

Is there a way to center the camera on 0,0 so that it remains there instead of following the circle?

```
 import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
 import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.scene.Group;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
 import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
 import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
 import javafx.util.Duration;

 public class Test extends Application
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage stage)
{
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Black");
        Group graph = new Group();
        root.setCenter(graph);
        graph.setLayoutX(250);
        graph.setLayoutY(250);

        Circle circle = new Circle(0,0,5);
        circle.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
        graph.getChildren().add(circle);

        Circle circle2 = new Circle(0, 0, 5);
        circle2.setFill(Color.AQUA);
        graph.getChildren().add(circle2);

    TranslateTransition t = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1000), circle);
    t.setFromX(0);
    t.setToX(100);
    t.setFromY(0);
    t.setToY(0);

    t.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    t.play();

    stage.setTitle("Circle Test");
    stage.setScene((new Scene(root, 500, 500)));
    stage.show();
}
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what is happening with the layout here, first note that the layout coordinates of the `Group` `graph` are ignored entirely, because you place `graph` in a layout container (a `BorderPane`). (Comment out the `setLayoutX` and `setLayoutY` lines and you will see they make no difference.) The layout container will size its child nodes according to 1. how much space it has for them, 2. the child nodes' min, preferred, and max sizes. Since the `BorderPane` doesn't have any other child nodes in this example, it wants to allocate all its available space to the `graph`. Since `graph` is in the center, if there is space it cannot allocate to it, it will center it, leaving the rest of the space unused.

`Group`s behave differently to `Region`s (which include `Control`s, `Pane`s, and their subclasses): according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) they are *not resizable* and *take on the collective bounds of their children*.

At the beginning of your animation, both circles are coincident, centered at `(0,0)` and with radius `5`: so their bounding boxes (and consequently the bounding box of the `Group`) has top left corner at `(-5,-5)` and width and height of `10`. This square `10x10` bounding box cannot be made bigger (since it's a `Group`, which is not resizable), and is centered on the screen. Since the `BorderPane` has `500` pixels of total width available, there are `490` pixels of unused width, which are divided equally on either side of the `Group` to center it: `245` to the left and `245` to the right. So the left edge of the `Group`, which is the left edge of both the circles, is at `x=245` in the `BorderPane` coordinate system.

At the end of the animation, one circle remains at `(-5,-5)` with width `10x10`, while the other has been translated `100` pixels to the right, so its bounding box extends from `(95, -5)` to `(105, 5)`. Consequently, the bounding box of the `Group`, which takes on the collective bounds of its child nodes, has top left at `(-5, -5)`, width `110` and height `10`. This box cannot be resized, so the `BorderPane`'s layout mechanism centers this box in the area it has available. Since the `BorderPane` has a width of `500` pixels available, there are 390 unused pixels in width which are divided equally on either side: `195` on the left of the `Group` and `195` on the right. So at this point, the left edge of the `Group`, which is the left edge of the untranslated circle, is at `x=195` in the `BorderPane` coordinate system. Consequently, at the end of the animation, the untranslated circle has moved `50` pixels (half of the translation distance) to the left in the `BorderPane`'s coordinate system.

A more natural thing to do here is to use a `Pane` instead of a `Group`. A `Pane` is resizable, so the `BorderPane` will simply expand it to fill all the available space. Thus it will sit in the top left of the `BorderPane` and fill the `BorderPane`. The bounds of the `Pane` start at `(0,0)` and extend to its width and height. Thus if you simply change `Group` to `Pane`, the untranslated circle will not move during the animation, as you want.

However, the circles will now both start in the top left of the pane instead of the center. If you want them to start in the center, you can change the coordinates of the circles themselves, so they start centered at `(250, 250)`:

```
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Test extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Black");
        Pane graph = new Pane();
        root.setCenter(graph);
        // graph.setLayoutX(250);
        // graph.setLayoutY(250);

        Circle circle = new Circle(250, 250, 5);
        circle.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
        graph.getChildren().add(circle);

        Circle circle2 = new Circle(250, 250, 5);
        circle2.setFill(Color.AQUA);
        graph.getChildren().add(circle2);

        TranslateTransition t = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1000), circle);
        t.setFromX(0);
        t.setToX(100);
        t.setFromY(0);
        t.setToY(0);

        t.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        t.play();

        stage.setTitle("Circle Test");
        stage.setScene((new Scene(root, 500, 500)));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you could use a `Pane` as the root, instead of a `BorderPane`. A plain `Pane` doesn't do any layout, so in this case the `layoutX` and `layoutY` settings will take effect. Thus you can revert the centers of the circles to `(0,0)`, and use the layout settings on `graph` to center it:

```
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Test extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Black");
        Pane graph = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(graph);
         graph.setLayoutX(250);
         graph.setLayoutY(250);

        Circle circle = new Circle(0, 0, 5);
        circle.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
        graph.getChildren().add(circle);

        Circle circle2 = new Circle(0, 0, 5);
        circle2.setFill(Color.AQUA);
        graph.getChildren().add(circle2);

        TranslateTransition t = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1000), circle);
        t.setFromX(0);
        t.setToX(100);
        t.setFromY(0);
        t.setToY(0);

        t.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        t.play();

        stage.setTitle("Circle Test");
        stage.setScene((new Scene(root, 500, 500)));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class name to whatever you want.

The problem you had was that you added it through the `setCenter()` method which automatically makes its center the center of the pane.

I hope this came in time.

```
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class NewClass extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #efefef");
        Group graph = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(graph);
        graph.setLayoutX(250);
        graph.setLayoutY(250);

        Circle circle = new Circle(0, 0, 5);
        circle.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
        graph.getChildren().add(circle);

        Circle circle2 = new Circle(0, 0, 5);
        circle2.setFill(Color.AQUA);
        graph.getChildren().add(circle2);

        TranslateTransition t = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1000), circle);
        t.setFromX(0);
        t.setToX(100);
        t.setFromY(0);
        t.setToY(0);

        t.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        t.setCycleCount(5);
        t.play();

        stage.setTitle("Circle Test");
        stage.setScene((new Scene(root, 500, 500)));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```